# Collecting excel file properties using Python 2

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, file

I'd like to collect some information about the properties for an excel file, such as:

> The Author, Last saved and Last printed.

Here is the code I used to get access time, modified time, change time and size.
    print('Access time  :', time.ctime(os.path.getatime(**file**)))

```
print('Modified time:', time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(__file__)))

print('Change time  :', time.ctime(os.path.getctime(__file__)))

print('Size         :', os.path.getsize(__file__))
```

information like: author, last saved, last printed

I was looking through these but nothing helpful:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

I have the difference between the original date and time of creation/modification (originally) and the date/time of download.

Answer (score 1):

what about (after `pip install openpyxl`):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
wb.properties
```

> Parameters:
>    creator='openpyxl', title=None, description=None, subject=None, identifier=None, language=None, created=datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 11,
>   14, 47, 30, 624845), modified=datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 11, 14, 47,
>   30, 624851), lastModifiedBy=None, category=None, contentStatus=None,
>   version=None, revision=None, keywords=None, lastPrinted=None

Comment: openpyxl is working only with .xlsx format and I need those properties for .xls format.