# Reading Metadata/Properties from Excel Files using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I am in an effort to parse metadata out of Excel files. I have tried openpyxl, but that does not give me the desired results.
I would like to read the Company Name and Author Name from properties.

Thank You

[This is the information I am trying to parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2lYj.png)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49220409/11301900. Also, are you really using Python 2?

Comment: Thank you, But like I mentioned openpyxl does not include Company Name.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40483700/727089) can help you find the right metadata tags.

Comment: Thank you, looks like it only includes Created, Modified, last_modified_by & creator.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73166006/1147688